# iOS8 HTTP Post network connection lost error

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, http-post

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1, iOS8.1 on iPhone 6 for testing.

Basically, I'm using Core Data to store data, `NSMutableURLRequest` to send HTTP Post request to `PHP` on server followed by inserting into `MySQL`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *allData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[allData setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DataStorage" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[allData setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

// Get Core Data
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * data = [context executeFetchRequest:allData error:&error];
// For all data in this entity
for (DataStorage * dt in data) {
    // Only sample content here
    NSString *postContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@&time=%@&",dt.id,dt.time];
    NSData *postData = [postContent dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [newRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [newRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [newRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [newRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:newRequest returningResponse:nil     error:&error];

    if (returnData)
    {
        NSString *json=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Resp string: %@",json);

        if (_deleteLocalSwitch.on) {
           [context deleteObject:dt];
        }
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
       break;
    }
}
```

I use the standard http post method found online (shown above), which *works perfect* if I send only a few entries (<20). But after the number of requests increased (>50 Core Data entries), I got the error **after exactly** 39 success requests:

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7fd8b0c86140 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd8b0c824e0 "The network connection was lost.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=xxxx.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=xxxx.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

I don't know why this error happens. A guess is caused by some kind of **time out** on server side or iOS.

I know I can try to build up an `XML` including all data and send the `XML` to server, which may solve this problem. But it's always better to know why this happened, and also save my life in changing lots of code.

Note: This is **not** a problem with Xcode / iOS simulator error, which can be found in other posts. I got the same error while I was testing the app on **both** iPhone6 & simulator. Also I got the same error while I was testing with **both** `localhost` & online server.

Thank you for reading this long question!